# facebook update: How to provide an SSL certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl, ssl-certificate

> You must provide an SSL certificate in the Dev App settings to avoid having your app disabled.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Do I have to upload my certificates anywhere? Where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the certificate is installed on your web server, you need to enter the https url in the dev app settings, I believe it's called "Secure Canvas URL". That's all that facebook requires of you.

Comment: Thank you. I have already some apps running that are available through https. I only was wondering what that "provide an SSL certificate in the Dev App settings" could mean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your certificate to your web server.
For more information about installing certificates, visit this link: https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO16226

Find out what kind of web server you're using and follow the instructions.  You may need to contact your web hosting administrator for help.

Comment: Thank you. I have the certificates installed on my web server. But in the quoted text they say I have to provide them "in the Dev App settings". My English is not so good. Am I misunderstanding this? I thought I have to upload the certificates to facebook (and was wandering why they don't just download them from my server).